# How to create website form with WhatsApp click to chat link

Tags: api, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to create a form on y website with Fields: Checkin Date, Chekout Date, Number of guests.
When user fill these and click on submit, it shall create custom whatsapp link and it will open whatsapp on user's device to send message. The submit url will look something link:

https://wa.me/MYNUMBER?text=I%27m%20interested%20in%20your%20property%20Chekin:%2010april%20Checkout:%2015april%2010Guests.%20Please%20provide%20quote

Can anyone help how to code this?

I tried making wordpress custom form but unable to achive the result. I'm thinking some API expert can help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: your requirement is not clear, is it that you need to open the whatsapp with the message regarding the provided keys (checkin Date, checkout date and no. of guest) with their values auto type in message box once you click submit?

Comment: @Jishnu Exactly yes

Comment: Ok, have you tried any thing so far?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go through [How to send information entered in a form to WhatsApp?](https://support.easyforms.dev/articles/how-to-submit-a-form-as-whatsapp-message). It clearly mention the usage of the below API end point.

`https://wa.me/PHONE_NUMBER?text={{ submission_text | url_encode }}`

The only thing you need to add here would be the actual `PHONE_NUMBER` and the actual text message within the `{{ ... }}` in the link

**Suggestion :**

You can create a function that can be called `onClick` / `onSubmit` for the submit event, which actually concatenate the result from multiple form fields (here `Checkin Date, Chekout Date, Number of guests` ) to create a string and send a request to the above given url. I think that would solve the issue and serve the purpose that you need.